# Renderizar JSON en una lista

Tags: javascript, json

Hola quiero renderizar en una lista los datos de un json de una api rest,por ejemplo quiero acceder a name.first, pero hasta el momento no me los muestra. No le encuentro el error  a mi código, me podrían ayudar por favor.

Json de la api
  https://randomuser.me/api/?nat=DE&gender=male&results=2&

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id="resultado"></div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
//1)Creamos el objeto XMLHTTPRequest
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // Abrimos la conexion
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  // Datos e impresion del template
  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      let nombres = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      // console.log(nombres);

      //Convierto el objeto JSON nombres en un array para poder recorrerlo.
      let arrayNombres = Array.from(nombres);

      let htmlNombres = "<h2>Nombres Generados</h2>";

      htmlNombres += `<ul class="lista">`;

      //Imprimir cada nombre
      arrayNombres.forEach(function (nombre) {
        htmlNombres += `

              <li>${results[nombre].name.first}
        `;
      });
      htmlNombres += "</ul>";
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = htmlNombres;
    }
  };

  //Enviar el Request
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: De donde viene *results*?

Comment: del json de la api https://randomuser.me/api/?nat=DE&gender=male&results=2&

Comment: no hay opción que uses JQuery? Fuera de eso, cuando estas haciendo results[nombre] no va a encontrar nada porque *nombre* es un valor; en lugar de eso deberías poner el índice del elemento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tema está en crear el array desde `results` de la respuesta y luego al iterar sobre cada `nombre` sacas el firstname desde ahí mismo.

agrego alternativa con `fetch` y `for .. in`

- faltaba el `</li>` también

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?nat=DE&gender=male&results=2&'
// Abrimos la conexion
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
// Datos e impresion del template
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (this.status === 200) {
    let res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    //Convierto el objeto JSON nombres en un array para poder recorrerlo.
    let arrayNombres = Array.from(res.results);

    //console.log(arrayNombres);

    let htmlNombres = "<h2>Nombres Generados</h2>";

    htmlNombres += `<ul class="lista">`;

    //Imprimir cada nombre
    arrayNombres.forEach(function(nombre) {
      // console.log(nombre)
      htmlNombres += `
              <li>${nombre.name.first}</li>
        `;
    });
    htmlNombres += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = htmlNombres;
  }
};

//Enviar el Request
xhr.send();

//  usando fetch
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?nat=DE&gender=male&results=2&')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    let nombres = data.results;
    var eldiv = document.querySelector('#resultado2');
    // console.log(nombres);
    eldiv.innerHTML = "<h2>Nombres Generados</h2>";
    eldiv.innerHTML += `<ul class="lista">`;
    for (n in nombres) {
      // console.log(nombres[n].name)
      eldiv.innerHTML += `<li>${nombres[n].name.first}</li>`;
    }
    eldiv.innerHTML += `</ul>`;
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
  <hr/>
  <div id="resultado2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @alo Malbarez.